# Grunt task to change names of css class inside css files and htmls or jade's

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, pug

I wonder are there any Grunt tasks which can change names of classes to something unique?

For e.g. 
.container -> .uniqueName_container

or just some random letters or number like google:
.container -> .jh72ab

But do it in both html/jade and css files?

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to support using functions to output replacement values; you could put your code for generating identifiers in there.

https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace

Example:

```
replacements: [{
  from: 'Foo',
  to: function (matchedWord) {   // callback replacement
    return matchedWord + ' Bar';
  }
}]
```

Comment: I'm not looking for simple text replacement but something more sophisticated, which will affect only css classes. Of course I can write regex by my own but I dont want to invent wheel another time.:)

Comment: for e.g this https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cssuglifier and this https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-prefix is doing job perfectly but only in css files :(